# How deeply should I peel sweet potatoes?

Tags: peeling, sweet-potatoes

When peeling sweet potatoes, should I just peel the outermost layer, or should I be peeling off the white part as well till I hit the orange inside? Should I keep going until it's all a darkish orange?

Comment: What variety of sweet potatoe is this? It is sort of a generic term for a multitude of non-potatoes. All the varieties I know of you shouldn't peel. Cook and eat as is

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't really matter.

A lot of people cook them with peel still on and peel it with their hands when cooked (Careful, hot!).
You can peel them before you cook them, and then it's just a question of taste I'd say.

Personally, I would peel off the white as well, though I'm not sure about this.

Comment: When roasting the sweet potatoes, you can also leave the skin on (after a good scrub of course).  Just like eating baked potatoes.  But better!

Comment: I leave the peels on for my mother--she loves them.  How much to peal, as the answerer has said, is a matter of personal preference.